# Сортировка в таблице(angular)

Tags: javascript, angular2, angular, angular4, angular5

Eсть таблица, при клике на его header-ы(name, surname, age или gender) нужно отсортировать по нажатым названиям, на пример если нажать по name, surname нужно будет отсортировать по алфавитному порядку, а по age возростанию

```js
filtername(name) {
  let frname = this.service.people.map(itm => itm['name'].first)
  frname.sort()
}
filtersurname(surname) {}
filterage(age) {
  // return age.map(itm=>itm.dob.age).sort((a,b)=>a-b)
}
filtergender(gender) {}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-dark">
  <tr>
    <th (click)="filtername(service.people)">Name</th>
    <th (click)="filtersurname(service.people)">Surname</th>

    <th (click)="filterage(service.people)">Age</th>
    <th (click)="filtergender(service.people)">Gender</th>
    <th>Photo</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of service.people | filters:gender">
    <td>{{item.name.first}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name.last}}</td>
    <td>{{item.dob.age}} </td>
    <td>{{item.gender}} </td>
    <td>
      <img src="{{item.picture.large}}" alt="">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

в консоле всё нормально сортируется, но не получается реализовать в таблице

база людей взята из https://randomuser.me/api?results=20

исходники тут https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkpnyt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В твоем примере ты сортируешь новый массив и никак его не используешь.
Директива `*ngFor` итерирует `service.people`. В момент сортировки ты создаешь новый массив `frname`. Никуда его не возвращаешь. После завершения функции результат сортировки просто уничтожается. По идее, тебе надо завести в компоненте переменную, содержащую копию исходного массива и все фильтрации и сортировки выполнять на ней.

К тому же, в темплейте ты во все сортировочные функции передаешь `service.people`. Я так понял, что это артефакты от твоих проб и ошибок. Но по сути это действие бесполезно, ведь весь сервис тебе доступен в `.ts` файле и обратно из темплейта его передавать нет необходимости.

Во время сортировки текста важно помнить о том, заглавные или строчные буквы используются. Текст при сравнении посимвольно конвертируется в число, эквивалентное позиции в таблице ASCII. Поэтому `а` и `А` это разные символьные значения. Cлова, начинающиеся на `Б` будут идти раньше, чем слова на `а`. Это стоит учитывать в алгоритме сортировки. Простой путь - это проверить, что ты сравниваешь, и если это строки, то привести обе строки либо к `UpperCase` либо к `LowerCase`.

```
if (typeof aPropValue === 'string') {
    return aPropValue.toLowerCase() <= bPropValue.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1;
} else {
    return aPropValue <= bPropValue ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Чуть усовершенствованный вариант с сортировкой в обе стороны:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3hwqtq

Answer (score 4):

Немного модифицировал ваш код

Посмотрите пример https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-og2vvk

Основные моменты:

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  gender: string = "all";
  people = [];
  filteredPeople = [];
  constructor(public service: DataService) {
    service.getPeoples().then(res => {
      this.people = this.filteredPeople = res.results;
    });
  }

  public sort(property: string): void {
    this.filteredPeople = this.people.sort((a, b) =>
      getDescendantProp(a, property) > getDescendantProp(b, property) ? 1 : -1
    );
  }
}
```

**data.service.ts**

```
export class DataService {
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { 


  } 
  public async getPeoples(): Promise<Tvyalner>{
    return this.http.get<Tvyalner>("https://randomuser.me/api?results=20").toPromise();
  }
}
```